# How to manually write code to show products in two different currencies, toggled by buttons

Tags: shopify, liquid

We have tried using some of the most popular Shopify Apps for this, and they work fine, but we have no way of controlling the exchange rate, on which basis the currencies are converted. This is very important for us, so we decided to find a way to code it manually.

I'm new to Shopify, but I have a sense of what I'll need to do within Liquid to effect the change. I'll need to change a Liquid variable somehow based on the selected currency and then recalculate it based on the value of that variable.

I am aware that you cannot trigger Liquid from Javascript, as they don't run concurrently, which makes the entire logic fall apart in a sense, or maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way.

How do I need to approach this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can check with 3rd party APPS, there are some APPS that also allow custom conversion rates for prices in their higher plans.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.